# addChild from child to parent scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense and maybe I have my game setup wrong. The issue I'm running into is that I have a GameScene filled with enemies I created with an enemy class.

Those enemy children create bullets. When the enemy dies I want the bullet to live on. Problem is the bullet won't do that if it's the child of the enemy object.

Is it possible to add my enemy bullet to my game scene from my enemy class? I tried things like:

```
  let myparent = self.parent as GameScene
  myparent.addChild(bullet)
```

But doesn't seem to work...

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a problem description. Most likely you forgot that node positions are relative, so if you add them to the scene you have to set the bullet's position to that of the node you used to add the bullet to, so that it starts out at the same position as the character that shoots. But generally what you are doing works, and is recommended. Actually I would even suggest not adding them to the scene, but a "bullet container" node which itself is on the scene, so that you can more easily influence all bullets at once if you needed to (ie pause game comes to mind).

Comment: Cool, that makes sense and it worked. I'll also add them to a bullet container node. Something I haven't thought about doing before.